# acts_as_taggable_on tag_cloud throws undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on, tag-cloud

I'm kind of stuck on creating a `tag_cloud`. I tried to do it like the `acts_as_taggable_on` documentation. You can find it here: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on (scroll down to 'Tag cloud calculations'.)

My post helper:

```
module PostHelper
    include ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsHelper
end
```

My post controller:

```
def tag_cloud
    @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags).order('count desc').limit(20)
end
```

The only thing I changed here from the documentation was to get it so the 20 most popular tags are shown.

My posts index view:

```
#alltags
    -tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class|
    =link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class
```

and I receive the following error: 
`undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass`

```
#alltags
    -tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class|
    =link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class
```

red highligthed in the error page is this line: `-tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class|`

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong as I'm following the documentation exactly, and searching the internet don't seem to help me either. I found one solution but I don't really want to do it that way, I feel there has to be an other, better, way. It's the solution in this stackoverflow question: [How to display a tag cloud from Acts as Taggable On on an index page in Ruby on Rails 3.2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973700/how-to-display-a-tag-cloud-from-acts-as-taggable-on-on-an-index-page-in-ruby-on)

I feel it has something to do with me using rails 4, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestion would be welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you copying the view vode right? It does not seem to to be in valid syntax, and what scripting are you used for your index view, is it has extension .html.erb?

Comment: No, thats haml. `.html.haml` The code is converted from .erb to .haml, that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and this worked for me, I hope it will work for you too.

Add a before filter in your post_controller like this.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
...
  before_action :tag_cloud
...
  def tag_cloud
    @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags).order('count desc').limit(20)
  end
...
end
```

After doing this I had also a routes error in this line:

```
link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class
```

I had to change the line like this:

```
<%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), :class => css_class %>
```

Now everything it's working on my app. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Heyy thanks for the solution, it worked, but can you please explain how you came up with this solution? I mean why adding ```before_action``` did the job?